# Formally smooth algebra of a field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and $R$ a local $k$-algebra. By Stacks \tag 00TX, if we assume that $R$ is of finite type, then the $R$ is smooth over $k$ if and only if $\Omega_{R/k}$ is free. I'm wondering if the analogous statement is true for formal smoothness, i.e is the formal smoothness of $R$ over $k$ equivalent to the freeness of $\Omega_{R/k}$?

My solution would be to use Stacks project 031I. We choose a polynomial ring P and a surjection $P\rightarrow R$ and denote by $J$ the kernel of $P\rightarrow R$. Then we have to show that the sequence 
$ (*) \ J/J^2 \rightarrow \Omega_{P/k}\otimes_P R \rightarrow \Omega_{R/k} \rightarrow 0$
is left exact and splits. If we can show that it is left exact, then by the projectivity of $\Omega_{R/k}$, we are done. By Stacks 00S2, we know that 
$ 0 \rightarrow H_1(L_{R/k}) \rightarrow J/J^2 \rightarrow \Omega_{P/k}\otimes_P R$. In http://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/people/manetti/dispense/defosing.pdf, it is writen (page 20, Def 9.2), that if $R$ is dg-algebra, and $M$ an $R$-dg-module ( and $k$ of characteristic zero!), then 
$H_i(L_{R/k}\otimes_R M)=\text{Tor}_i^R(L_{R/k},M)$.
If we assume that $R$ is a dg-algebra, then for $i=1$ and $M=R$ we get that $H_1(L_{R/k})=0$. Hence the sequence (*) is left exact and we are done. However I'm not confident in this solution.

Comment: Field extensions are formally smooth if and only if they are separable <https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031U>. However, since we are in characteristic zero, this is no issue.

Comment: As you point out, $R$ is formally smooth (for the discrete topology) if and only if $H_1(L_{R/k})=0$ and $\Omega_{R/k}$ is projective (for any homomorphism $k\to R$ of commutative rings). Now, I don't know why you say that in your case $H_1(L_{R/k})=\text{Tor}_1^R(L_{R/k},R)$ vanishes. Note that for instance for an inseparable field extension $l|k$,   $\Omega_{l/k}$ is free but $H_1(L_{l/k})\neq 0$. Similarly, in characteristic zero there are $k$-algebras $R$ with $H_1(L_{R/k})\neq 0$. So you claim $H_1(L_{R/k})=0$ must use char. 0 and freeness of $\Omega_{R/k}$.